# WPF, Entity Framework, and SQL Server CE

Tags: wcf, frameworks, sql-server-ce, entity

I'm developing a WPF application, and some guidance would be appreciated. The application needs to store some data locally. The data doesn't need to be shared, but multiple users can log into the application, each with a different profile. Can anyone advise me on the wisdom of using the Entity Framework 4.0 with SQL Server CE in this context, please? My area of expertise (should that term even be applicable) is web applications over .NET, so this type of development is not so familiar to me.

Any input most gratefully received.

Cheers!

-- 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of blogs about WPF, SQL CE 4.0 and EF4:
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: Thanks a lot - much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't vote up, as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 4 and SQLCE 4.0 should work pretty well. There were a few glitches with EF4 and SQLCE 3.5, but those seem to have been worked out. The biggest problem with EF4 and SQLCE 4 is that the Visuyal Studio tooling is incomplete. But if you do a search on StackOverflow for my user ID, you should see a couple of threads I started when I was figuring out how to make the two play together nicely. I am also planning to do a CodeProject areticle on my research, so you might also look there.

Comment: Thanks a lot - much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't vote up, as I don't have enough reputation yet.